# Custom HTML Form linked to PHP in Wordpress pulling fatal error

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm new to forums but always read them to see such useful advice. I have taken many hours to do my best at solving this code I'm writing for my first ever plugin on wordpress. It is meant for a user to be able to use a custom HTML form to submit a search type to the database, and retrieve user information based on form entry via POST. For some reason, after i click submit, it keeps pulling a critical error. Other times when I simplify the coding to an if else statment where the else is to echo "hello world", it will read the initial 'if' statement on page load, but after submit data in the form, it redirects to a 404 page.

Because of this I have determined the action statement is correctly linking, and the code itself is live whenever i load the page (it shows the 'if' statment on page load), but perhaps there is an error with how the data is being retrieved since whenever i click submit it sends to a 404 page? I'm putting the full code below for php (the one that runs a critical error, not the simplified version). Any help would be much appreciated!

**Below is the code for the HTML form:**

```html
<form action="trainer_data_pull" method="post"; id="trainer-pull">
        
        <label for="text" style="color:#35bef2">
            First Name: </label>
            
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" autocomplete="on">
       
       <br>
       <br>
        <label for="email" style="color:#35bef2">Email Address</label>
       
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="on">
       
       <br>
       <br>
       
        <input type="submit" value="Check Database">
    </form>
```

**and here is the code for the php file it is linked too:**

function trainer_data_pull_results() {

```
   htmlspecialchars($_POST['submit']);
   
    
    if(empty($_POST)){
    echo "The results will be displayed here";
    }
    else{
        $global_wpdb;
        
        $connection=mysqliconnect( //I know these are correct because I've single tested the connection before so I'm leaving this out for security!);
            if($connection) {
             echo "Connection established! <br>";
             }
             else {
             die("Connection Failed Due To: ".mysqli_connect_error());
             }
}

$global_wpdb;
$table_name = “foo_bar";
$field = $_POST[‘Email’];
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results(SELECT * FROM $table_name where user_email = "".$field."");
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {

    echo $retrieved_data->title;
    exit;
    }
```

add_action('results','trainer_data_pull_results');
//This is a custom hook that others can hook onto with the add action which I am also just learning about and not sure if it is needed or not! I figured adding more is better than less...

add_shortcode('trainer_data_pull_results','trainer_data_pull_results');

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you mean using things link htmlspecialcharacters() ? Is this what they mean by "sanitizing" data? I'll read more up on it but wasn't sure where to necessarily include that (maybe before the action on the html form)?

Comment: Never sanitize data! Use prepared statements for SQL queries and use `htmlspecialcharacters()` when outputting anything in HTML. Don't mix them together

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction! I'm still uncertain the difference between sanitizing data and using htmlspecialcharacters (I thought htmlspecialcharacters doesn't allow for java code to be utilized through a form since it "parses" the <> marks, which turns them into %, which means to sanitize the data)?

Comment: `htmlspecialcharacters` formats the data so that it can be properly displayed in HTML without breaking HTML. This has nothing to do with Java (I think you are confusing Java and JavaScript). Sanitizing means removing unwanted information. In this case, you don't want to remove anything. Whatever the user provides should be saved in the database in the exact same format, and then properly formatted when displayed in HTML.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your responses. I am going to read up more and try to run the code again with your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach than this one. I have tried to do what you are doing without success, but using Ajax and hooking the form submit to a PHP function to process the form information works for me. Implementing AJAX in WordPress is a bit different of what you will normally do, but here is an [explanation of it](https://wpengine.com/resources/using-ajax-in-wordpress/).

Also, for what is worth, the form action property is trying to take you to a URL `(action="trainer_data_pull")` that does not exist when you submit, that is why you are seeing a 404.And the semi colon after `method="post"` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you kindly! I have read online to find that it is a security risk to link straight to a php file, and to instead use the wp api. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, the right way to do it is to use the API, which means to use the ajax file that WP uses to execute Ajax in the backend and hook the form to an Ajax call, but again, the Ajax call will not be structured as a normal one, you will have to read about how to do it properly.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your help I will read up on it and try again! Best wishes to you!!